# Pandas GroupBy Total Row for Days of the Week, then sum only on one column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I attempted this by:

```
df = {
'inc_date':['06-Jul-2020','06-Jul-2020','06-Jul-2020','07-Jul-2020','08-Jul-2020','08-Jul-2020','09-Jul-2020',],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(df))
df['inc_Day_of_Week'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['inc_date']).day_name() # Create ddd of the INC
print(df)

dfTemp = df.groupby(['inc_Day_of_Week']).size()
dfTemp = dfTemp.reset_index(name='inc_volume').sort_index()
# Add sorting so days of week appear Mon-Fri
cats = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
dfTemp['inc_Day_of_Week'] = pd.Categorical(dfTemp['inc_Day_of_Week'], categories=cats, ordered=True)
dfTemp.loc['Total'] = dfTemp.sum(numeric_only=True)
display(dfTemp)
print("", end='\n')

    inc_Day_of_Week inc_volume
0   Monday          3.0
1   Thursday        1.0
2   Tuesday         1.0
3   Wednesday       2.0
Total   NaN         7.0
```

This is whats required except for the `NaN` i.e. How to remove the `NaN` only sum on the one column?

```
Total           7.0
```

I tried to append but this does fail:

```
dfTotal1 = [[dfTemp.inc_volume.sum()]]
dfTotal2 = pd.DataFrame(dfTotal1,columns=['inc_volume'])
dfTemp.append(dfTotal2)
```

Comment: Can you add code to recreate your original data?  Or a portion of it?

Comment: Sure, one second

Comment: Added another method @Peter Lucas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing `NaN` values with `""` should solve your query. After you add the `Total` row to the `dfTemp` DataFrame, add this line of code

**CODE**

```
dfTemp.fillna(value="", inplace=True)
```

If you want to avoid calculating sum on categorical variables directly,

```
dfTotal = pd.DataFrame({"inc_Day_of_Week": "", "inc_volume": dfTemp.inc_volume.sum()}, index=["Total"])
dfTemp = pd.concat([dfTemp, dfTotal])
```

**OUTPUT**

```
          inc_Day_of_Week  inc_volume
0              Monday         3.0
1            Thursday         1.0
2             Tuesday         1.0
3           Wednesday         2.0
Total                         7.0
```

Comment: I need to not sum on the inc_Day_of_Week in the first place as in other df's all the values in this column will concatenate instead of showing NaN

Comment: `numeric_only=True`. This argument you gave makes sure that the sum is calculated only for numerical values. However, the `NaN` value is coming because, when calculating the sum over columns, It avoids the `inc_Day_of_Week` column. So in the resulting series, the value of the `inc_Day_of_Week` column will be missing and while adding the series to the DataFrame, the `NaN` value will be added to the column

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this,

```
import pandas as pd

df = {
'inc_date':['06-Jul-2020','06-Jul-2020','06-Jul-2020','07-Jul-2020','08-Jul-2020','08-Jul-2020','09-Jul-2020',],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(df))
df['inc_Day_of_Week'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['inc_date']).day_name()
df = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('inc_Day_of_Week').count()).reset_index()
df.loc['Total'] = df.sum(numeric_only=True)
df.fillna(value='',inplace=True)
```